# Is there a more efficient approach than C# Action delegates for avoiding this code duplication?

Tags: c#, delegates, refactoring, code-duplication

As much as possible I want to avoid unnecessary duplication of code. In my scenario described below I have used `Action` delegates to avoid code duplication. However, when using the `Action` delegate approach, the code becomes approximately 50%-80% slower.

Is there a more efficient approach from a performance perspective than `Action` delegates to avoid code duplication in the scenario described below?

I have two methods that are equivalent except for the innermost statement of a lengthy loop:

```
public T[] MethodA<T>(T[] from)
{
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    var j = GetIndex(i);
    to[j] = from[i];    // This statement differs in MethodA and MethodB
  }
  ...
  return to;
}

public T[] MethodB<T>(T[] from)
{
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    var j = GetIndex(i);
    to[i] = from[j];    // This statement differs in MethodA and MethodB
  }
  ...
  return to;
}
```

To avoid code duplication I have implemented a helper method that takes an `Action` delegate.  Invocation of the delegate replaces the variable statement, like this:

```
private T[] HelperMethod<T>(T[], Action<T[], T[], int, int> action)
{
  ...
  for (var i = 0; i < len; ++i)
  {
    var j = GetIndex(i);
    action(from, to, i, j);    // Invoke the Action delegate
  }
  ...
  return to;
}
```

Then I can reduce `MethodA` and `MethodB` as follows:

```
public T[] MethodA<T>(T[] from)
{
  return HelperMethod(from, (src, dest, src_idx, dest_idx) => dest[dest_idx] = src[src_idx]);
}

public T[] MethodB<T>(T[] from)
{
  return HelperMethod(from, (src, dest, dest_idx, src_idx) => dest[dest_idx] = src[src_idx]);
}
```

Note that the only difference between the refactored `MethodA` and `MethodB` is the order of the `src_idx` and `dest_idx` in the `Action` signatures of the `HelperMethod` calls.

Comment: how did you measure that 50-80% performance degradation? It sounds unlikely

Comment: I did timing comparisons within my unit tests before and after the refactoring. Granted, the above code is a simplified version of my implementation, but before refactoring the elapsed time (measured with the Stopwatch class inside the unit test) was 1.6-1.8 seconds, whereas after refactoring the elapsed time was 2.6-2.7 seconds.

Comment: It is unlikely to beat direct assignment with any form of function call - so if it is performance critical you already have solution that works for you...

Comment: Yes, you are right, Alexei, thanks. After further testing inspired by demoncodemonkey's response below it fortunately turned out that it was very inexpensive to test a boolean inside the loop, so my solution is to stick with direct assignment, where the assignment route is tested in every iteration of the loop.

Comment: Is the loop exactly as written, or is there much more code inside it you've missed out? You could move the `if` to just outside the loop and just duplicate the contents of the loop... Something of a middle ground.

Comment: I oversimplified the loop contents in the example above, sorry for not being entirely clear. There is quite a lot of code also inside the loop, so the `if` statement needs to be inside the loop in order to avoid duplication as much as possible. Thanks anyway, Rawling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a parameter to the method and do A or B depending on the parameter.
I don't like it but I'm just saying it could be done. I actually prefer the Action way.

Comment: Thanks. True, I had thought about that and dismissed it because then I would need to perform an `if` or `switch` or similar statement for every item in the loop. It is not entirely evident from the example above, but the loop also contains quite a lot of code that I do not want to duplicate.

Comment: On second thought, I had originally dismissed this approach without testing it :-) Apparently, the `if` statement is extremely "cheap", because the timing is about the same before and after refactoring when using the (bool) parameter approach. I'll go for this solution. Thanks, @demoncodemonkey!